# xcode class stays nill

Tags: xcode, class, initialization

I have created the following class, hoewever when I try to import the class into another file, create an instance and get or set any property, it does not work. I have found with debugging that when I make an instance of the class it stays nill.

When I saw that, I made an init method like below to allocate memory to the properties:

```
-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        numberName = [[NSString alloc] init];
        numberNode = [[CCNode alloc] init];
    }

    return self
}
```

It still did not work and the instance of the class stays nill when debugging.
(I also tried to create my own getters and setters, but I geuss this is not part of the problem since it has not been initialized in the first place.)

.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Number : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger numberId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *numberName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CCNode *numberNode;

@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "Number.h"

@implementation Number

@synthesize numberId;
@synthesize numberName;
@synthesize numberNode;

@end
```

Comment: All the above looks mostly ok; I had to put underscores ('_') in front of ivars in the initialization routine (FYI: you don't need the @synthesize anymore) … how did you create an instance?

Answer (score 2):

You're failing to return the initialized object.

```
-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        numberName = [[NSString alloc] init];
        numberNode = [[CCNode alloc] init];
    }

    return self; // <---- This is what you're missing.
}
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to type that. I have returned self, else it would have generated an error!

Comment: Ok. Correct your question and the crowd can go from there. We can only work with what you give us.